# Inline list items aligned left and right

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-lists

I have a list of 2 pieces of text, I want them to display inline with each-other, but have one float to the left of the parent div, and the other float to the right of the parent div, without adding id's etc.

I tried using the CSS selector

```
.rating li:first-child
```

&

```
.rating li:nth-child(2)
```

and set different text-algin properties to each, but it's not working. 
Does anyone have any suggestions?

The HTML is:

```
      <ul class="rating">
        <li>Below Average</li>
        <li>Above Average</li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: What's not working? Please show your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you stated "float" in your question so that's one option or you can add `flexbox` for progressive enhancement in modern browsers.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/uh9khfa2/)

```css
.rating {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

li {
background: #bada55;
}

.rating li:first-child {
    float: left;
}

.rating li:nth-child(2) {
    float: right;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
      <ul class="rating">
        <li>Below Average</li>
        <li>Above Average</li>
     </ul>

      <ul class="rating flex">
        <li>Flex Left</li>
        <li>Flex Right</li>
     </ul>
```